# Calling a method by injection (from component to component) in Angular is not binding {{}}

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I have created a project in stackblitz to easily see what is happening. I am calling a method from one component using a button in another component. It executes the method but for some reason is not bidding the variables.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-com1-com2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcom2%2Fcom2.component.ts

Please, do not forget to open the console in stackblitz to see more information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template variable and call child component like below:

```
<button (click)="childComp.modifyMessage()">change message</button>
<app-com2 #childComp></app-com2>
```

Comment: Hey @MohammadNiazmand I wanted to use your solution in the stackblitz but it doesn't work. Could you please do one sandbox and share the link? Thanks!!

Comment: I missed double quotes.Just replace above code with <button (click)=changeMessage()>change message</button> in com1.component.html